# QLIKVIEW Formula para alimentar o POISSON

Tags: matemática, business-intelligence

Preciso de ajuda para descobrir o valor para uma formula **POISSON**

Tenho a tabela abaixo:

[image]

Com a formula **POISSON** do excel **=POISSON(10;11.97;TRUE)** Recebo o valor de 35,07%

```
=POISSON( Numero de Peças ; Peças Entregues dentro do prazo 7 dias;TRUE)
```

O resultado com o numero de peças (10) me dá uma disponibilidade de: **35,07%**

E eu tenho uma variável **vDisponibilidade** que eu informo a disponibilidade que eu quero atingir.

Ex: Se eu quero a disponibilidade de 95%, eu preciso de 18 peças.

```
=POISSON(18;624;TRUE) = 96,34%
```

Preciso de uma formula que me dê a quantidade de peças para que o **POISSON** me retorne a disponibilidade que eu quero.

Se precisar de 35% = 10 peças.

Se precisar de 95% = 18 peças.

> - Peças Entregues dentro do prazo 7 dias = 624 / ( 365 / 7 )

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver meu problema, espero que possa ajudar alguém.
Ou se tiverem solução melhor me avisem.

Quebrei a formula do Poisson

[image: POISSON]

Colocando no Script de Carga

```
PECAS:
Load *
Resident LISTA_PECAS;

//For para passar por todos as linhas da tabela
For i=0 to NoOfRows('PECAS')-1;

    //Quantidade Peças para atender no Ano
    Let NUM_PECAS=Peek('NUM_PECAS', $(i), 'PECAS'); 

    // Numero de Serie da Peça para criar a relação
    Let SERIAL=Peek('SERIAL', $(i), 'PECAS'); 

    Let tDisponibilidade = 0; //Seta a disponibilidade em 0 para cada linha que passar 

    For QNT_PECAS=0 to $(vMaxPoisson); // For para fazer o acumulado do POISSON para ver a disponibilidade usando variável QNT_PECAS começando com 0

        Let PECAS_POR_PRAZO = ($(vPRAZO)/365)*$(NUM_PECAS); //Conta Para saber as peças por prazo para atender a disponibilidade anual

        Let tDisponibilidade = tDisponibilidade + ((exp(-$(PECAS_POR_PRAZO ))*pow($(PECAS_POR_PRAZO ),$(QNT_PECAS)))/Fact($(QNT_PECAS)));
        // Acumula o valor do POISSON, a formula sem acumular é:
        //=EXP(-PECAS_POR_PRAZO)*PECAS_POR_PRAZO^(QNT_PECAS)/(FATORIAL(QNT_PECAS))


        if(tDisponibilidade >= $(vDisponibilidade)) then

            Tabela_Disponibilidade:
            LOAD * INLINE [
            SERIAL, QNT_PECAS, DISPONIBILIDADE
            $(SERIAL), $(QNT_PECAS), $(tDisponibilidade)
            ];          
            exit for; //Sai do For e para de Acumular quando atender a disponibilidade

        end if

    Next QNT_PECAS;

Next i;
```